# How to verify openjpa enhancing entities happened successfully

Tags: java, jpa, ibm-mobilefirst, openjpa, mobilefirst-server

We are enhancing entities at build time in our project. We are getting build successful when running enhancer build. However when we add

```
openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses=unsupported
```

we get an error saying

> *This configuration disallows runtime optimization, but the following listed types were not enhanced at build time or at class load time
>   with a javaagent*

and 
lists all our entities.
All these things started when we are getting outofmemory(memory leak) error when loading our api's. Using openjpa 1.2.2, java 1.7
Any suggestions?

Comment: How is the related to IBM MFP server? Are you bundling your own OpenJPA with your Adapter?

Comment: @S.A.Norton  I am using ibm's mfp server which has openjpa 1.2.2 bundled in it and u r right.

Comment: Just to clarify - you are using OpenJPA in your adapter project and for this you are not packaging your own OpenJPA, but rather using the OpenJPA MFP server provides?

Comment: @S.A.Norton Stanley yes.using OpenJPA MFP server provides.

Comment: fyi using mfp 7.0, using parent last delegation,using JTA transaction, container managed trasaction with db2.

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter if you are making use of OpenJPA provided by MFP server, and making modifications to it or performing configuration changes, you should not. This OpenJPA layer is used by MFP server for its working and any changes you make to it can cause runtime issues.

You could try packaging your own version of OpenJPA for use within your adapter and do the enhancements there.

Comment: could you provide any webpage stating this or any openbug?
i am not making changes to openjpa, i am enhancing entities using enhancer.xml(did i interpret it wrong?).

Answer (score 0):

Ran in to similar issue. Later discovered that it was a silly error in script. The project was built, the enhancer was run and then again the project was re-built. This overwrote the enhanced classes. How is that you are running the enhancer?